# Unable to resolve module @react-navigation/native-stack from Navigation.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, cross-platform, hybrid-mobile-app

Android Bundling failed 163ms
Unable to resolve module @react-navigation/native-stack from Navigation.js: @react-navigation/native-stack could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules

````
        import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
    import React from 'react'
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
    import Login from './Screens/Login';
    const Navigation = () => {
    
    
        const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
      return (
       
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    
      )
    }
    
    export default Navigation```
````

Comment: Have you installed @react-navigation/native-stack? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#installation

Comment: yah have you installed all the dependencies properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting node_modules and package-lock.json from the project. And Re-install them using "npm install". This worked for me and definitely should work for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).